# ListView's items are not occupying the entire device space

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

My listView contains 7 items. I want these 7 items to cover up the entire device space.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".DaysList">


        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            >


        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

My **onCreate()** method:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ListView listView=getListView();

            listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

            String[] values = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
                    "Thursday","Friday", "Saturday","Sunday" };

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);



            setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

**Expected Output:**
[image]

**Actual Output:**
[image]

Comment: You should use a vertical LinearLayout with layout_weight rather than a ListView, if you always have 7 items

Comment: Did you tried to change layout_height of listview from "match_parent" to "wrap_content"?

Comment: @fractalwrench i used android:orientation=vertical, still the same result.

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit yeah, i tried that

Comment: ListView doesn't work this way that you can fit all it's items equally on visible screen. You have to use other Layout instead of ListView to achieve that. Like put 7 TextViews in a LinearLayout and set all TextView's `layout_weight=1`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed items count, you don't need a listView but a simple linear layout with 7 TextViews in your case and set a weight for the Textviews height like :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_monday"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Monday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tuesday"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Tuesday" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom adapter which measures the height of the device screen and spreads the items

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".DaysList">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    String[] values = new String[]{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new Adapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    public Adapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Adapter(Context context, int resource, String[] items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        int fullHeight = parent.getHeight();
        int itemHeight = fullHeight / getCount() ;

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = itemHeight;
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. Misunderstood your question. My edit will give you the 'cover up the entire device space'. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

By default ListView contains in ScrollView which has infinite height. So even if you only declare listView as a wrap content, it will fill out the entire as long as there is empty space as in your example. You can fix it by calling this method AFTER you set up your adapter:

```
public boolean setListViewHeight(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter != null) {

        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

        View item = listAdapter.getView(0, null, listView);
        item.measure(0, 0);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, numberOfItems * item.getMeasuredHeight());
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]